# Accessing The Character Right after a blank space

Tags: java

I want to access character **right after a blank space** and **convert it into Capital**.
I know capitalizing and removing blank space but can't access the character after a space.

I want to convert: `"File to be uploaded"` to `"FileToBeUploaded"`.

Comment: Try something and let us know what worked.

Comment: Get the index of the space with indexOf. Add 1.

Answer (score 3):

**Without Regex**

First thing to do would be to split on `" "`..

```
String[] tokens = string.split(" ");
```

Then the next step is to cycle through each token, and grab the first letter.

```
for(int x = 0; x < tokens.length; x++)
{
    String token = tokens[x];
    String firstLetter = String.valueOf(tokens[x].charAt(0));
    // After you have first letter, it's just a case of moving to upper case..
    firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    tokens[x] = firstLetter + tokens[x].substring(1, tokens[x].length());
}
```

**Note**: I didn't use a `foreach` loop because a `foreach` will only read.

Finally, stick it all together. You can do this in the same loop. If you don't want to change the array itself, you can use a `foreach` in this context, which will look nicer; as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Use a string builder for string creation.

for(String token : tokens)
{
    String firstLetter = String.valueOf(token.charAt(0));
    // After you have first letter, it's just a case of moving to upper case..
    firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();        
    sb.append(firstLetter + token.substring(1, token.length()););       
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: That wouldn't give a ConcurrentModificationException anyway. Arrays don't throw ConcurrentModificationExceptions. Plus Collections only throw them when you add / remove items while iterating, which you aren't doing here. You can't use foreach because foreach only reads, any modifications you make aren't written back to the array.

Comment: Well.. I had the right idea, just the wrong reason :P I'll edit now.

Comment: String concatenation with + is evil, better use StringBuilder.

Comment: Hmm.. agreed. Editing.

Comment: `String` class doesn't have a `getCharAt` method, it's simply `charAt` and you don't need to use the variable firstLetter ( which is declared at each loop iteration ), you can use `sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(token.charAt(0)) + token.substring(1, token.length()));` inside your loop

Comment: I added in the extra variable for readability, given that I wasn't sure at what level OP is at.

Comment: Still, you shoud declare `firstLetter` before entering the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String str = "File to be uploaded";
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String i : arr) {
        sb.append(i.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + i.substring(1, i.length()));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

// With regex it is very simple

```
private String capitalEachWord(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+\\w"); // Search for one or more space
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) m.appendReplacement(buffer, m.group().toUpperCase());
    m.appendTail(buffer); // add to last
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This form of a string is called [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

As you can't change the characters in a string (since it's immutable), you have to build a new String by iterating over the characters. If you encounter a white space, skip that character but remember to capitalize the next.

```
public static String toCamelCase (String s) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capitalizeNextChar = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            capitalizeNextChar = true;
        } else {
            if (capitalizeNextChar) {
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                capitalizeNextChar = false;
            }
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**  you can also use `split()`

```
String abc = "File to be uploaded";
String temp[] = abc.split(" ");
String Result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
  {
   if (temp[i].length() > 0) 
      Result = Result + temp[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()   + temp[i].substring(1, temp[i].length());
  }
System.out.println(Result);
```

**Output:**

```
FileToBeUploaded
```